# Firebase nodejs admin sdk - Delete file from firebase storage gives the socket hang up error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

```
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL: dbUrl
    });
    
    const storage = admin.storage();
    
    const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file("videos/342.mp4");
    file
       .exists()
       .then(data => {
          if (data[0]) {
             return file.delete();
          } else {
             return Promise.resolve();
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
           console.error(`Failed to delete video`, err);
        });
```

The error that is caught in the catch block is

> FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: socket hang up